# How would I make a tube-like edge for my model

Tags: modeling

I've recently found myself unable to perform a seemingly simple action in Blender while creating my model. I want to create a "tube-like" edge where 2 of the parts connect together, but nothing I've tried has worked, since extruding the edge results in a plane that I can't scale properly. I'm unsure of what to do, as I'm quite new to Blender and don't fully understand what I'm doing. Explaining what I want to achieve seems a bit hard, so I've added some images! I'd really appreciate some help!

[image: What my reference is, you can see the circular edge]

[image: What I'm stuck with]

[image: This part]
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello it's hard to understand what is your object, do you have other pictures?

Comment: I added more images, I'm trying to create the bump that I've circled in red, but have little clue how to. I just need it do go along the top edges of the model, just like in the image. The same bump can be seen around the window.

Comment: I would take the edge in question, duplicate it into an object that I convert from Mesh to a Curve, and have a cylinder use the Curve modifier.  See my Answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example:

[image]

I started with a cube where I removed the top face and Beveled to look similar to your target shape.   I then selected non-Manifold edges (or you can select these manually), 'D' (Duplicate), 'P' Separate Selection (into a new object 'Cube.001'),

[image]

I then converted the Cube.001 into a curve that will bend a new mesh:

[image]

Then I added a cylinder and subdivided *only* the vertical edges to make sure it had sufficient edges to bend along the curve,

[image]

and then used the Curve modifier to fit it.  (you may have to adjust the axis of conformance, and move the cylinder or Object :: Apply :: Location):

[image]

My example: [image]

You can add the Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth the outcome.